# error while installing django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to learn Django framework.
I have windows machine and on that I have installed virtual machine (oracle VM VirtualBox manager).
I have python installed on that.

I dont see pip installed on this VM. so i tried to install django via below:

```
 wget https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.10.1/tarball/
```

This gives the following error:

```
 Resolving www.djangoproject.com... 162.242.220.127,      2001:4802:7801:102:be76:4eff:fe20:789f
 Connecting to www.djangoproject.com|162.242.220.127|:443... connected.
 ERROR: cannot verify www.djangoproject.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3':
 Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
 ERROR: certificate common name `djangoproject.com' doesn't match requested host name `www.djangoproject.com'.
 To connect to www.djangoproject.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
 Unable to establish SSL connection
 --------------------
```

so i tried below:

```
wget --user=username --password --no-check-certificate https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.10.1/tarball/
```

but still error:

```
ERROR: cannot verify www.djangoproject.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3':
Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
ERROR: certificate common name `djangoproject.com' doesn't match requested host name `www.djangoproject.com'.
To connect to www.djangoproject.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Rather than trying to download the tarball, you should install pip.

Comment: Your problem is with the VM you're working on... what OS/version is it?

Comment: And FYI, get pip working- you won't be able to do anything with just the tarball (hell, if I remember correctly Django itself has multiple hard dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

Get pip installed and working and then install it using pip as suggested

**Official instructions**
[check out instructions][1]
Per http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html:

Download get-pip.py, being careful to save it as a .py file rather than .txt. Then, run it from the command prompt:

```
python get-pip.py

pip install django

pip freeze | grep Django

      Django==1.9.9     # to see which version is installed
```

---

ps. Keep in mind, once you have pip installed, if you run pip and you still get something like "command not found" you may have to just close the shell and start it again.

Comment: I went to the link given by you and copied get-pip.py.
After running got below error:-

` python get-pip.py
    File "get-pip.py", line 43
    _b85alphabet = (b"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: In order to help you, u should provide at least what your operating system is? OS? windows? linux? If linux are u root or a user? are u using sudo? do you have enough permissions? if windows: are u admin?

Comment: I have installed virtual box on windows machine.
VirtualBox-5.0.2-102096-Win

Comment: What version of python have u installed? provide a copy paste of the entire error. Also try to install pip from this link https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py     Keep in mind Pip no longer supports Python 2.4,

Comment: Yes I am using old version of python .
>>> sys.version_info
(2, 4, 3, 'final', 0)

what should I do? 
download new VM setup altoegether ?
or upgrade python ?how ?

Comment: First lets get some some info correct: U are running windows on a virtual machine. When I asked for os, u replied " i have installed virtual box on windows." Which is good but you still have an OS installed on the virtual box. Install the latest version of python 3.x.x. and you should be good to go. Unless u really need the old version of python 2.4.x. If that is not the case, just download the latest copy and you should be fine. to avoid any issues, don't upgrade. Uninstall python 2.4.x.. You may have to reboot. download the latest stable release and install it. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

why not just download from [github repo](https://github.com/django/django/archive/master.tar.gz)

in that way this will work

`wget https://github.com/django/django/archive/master.tar.gz`

Comment: error :-
ERROR: cannot verify github.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to github.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

Comment: It is pretty important to be able to install dependencies to have a working Django environment.

Answer (score -2):

(I am assuming you use Ubuntu on this VM)

Just install pip with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
```

Comment: Seems likely that the certificate error would persist through this step...